# Specific problems - but general environment, or specific ones?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I'm a bit confused regarding the "scope" of SO questions.

On one hand, somewhere I read, people are unsatisfied with questions which are so specific that can't help others but the one who asked it. Personally, I also prefer not to mention too many precise details (e.g. "I'm making a Reddit analyzer/SO tracker/ Facebook app/etc.") but only the problem itself, often even with the code simplified to focus on the error and debugging.

On the other hand, recently someone has told me, that (despite I declared a specific error message in a specific function call or variable pass or anything) my question is too broad and I should provide, what do I *actually* do. However, I can't understand how **that** can be constructive to the site as a whole.

What's your view?

Comment: Can you link to the question in question?

Comment: @Pekka웃 of course: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327557/how-can-i-differentiate-requests-from-various-sources

Comment: Right now, the question looks at first like a "my code doesn't work" question, as it has a single sentence of explanation followed by what appears to be a code dump. I would either remove the code and write an explanation of what you want (as one of the commenters mention, inputs/outputs), or actually include code you've tried to get working, so that people can try it and show you the way. I don't know node/express at all, but it seems like what people are saying is to look at how routing works in express and take advantage of that.